# Create Window without Registering a WNDCLASS?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Is it absolutely necessary to always build and register a new WNDCLASS(EX) for your application? And then use the lpszClassName for the main window?

Isn't there some prebuilt class name we can use for a main window, like there is "Button" and "Edit" for buttons and text-boxes etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a mini app out of a dialog resource, you use CreateDialog() instead of CreateWindow().  Boilerplate code could look like this, minus the required error checking:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "resource.h"

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: 
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL) {
            DestroyWindow(hDlg);
            PostQuitMessage(LOWORD(wParam)-1);
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    HWND hWnd = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, DlgProc);
    if (hWnd == NULL) DebugBreak();
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

Which assumes you created a dialog with the resource editor using id IDD_DIALOG1.

Comment: You can, if you are feeling very brave, create dialogs directly via CreateWindowEx, using the WC_DIALOG style.

Comment: Seems that [EndDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is supposed to be used with modal dialogs (those created by functions such as [DialogBox()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For _[modeless](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)_ dialogs like above, one should use [DestroyWindow()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: You are right.  It was quite happy with EndDialog(), probably a mistake common enough to handle it in the winapi :)

Comment: Don't we need IsDialogMessage in message pumping loop?

Comment: You need it for a modeless dialog, this isn't.

Answer (score 3):

There are no pre-defined window classes for top-level application windows. You must register a window class for your application, or use a dialog.