# MessageBox won't work when handling WM_DESTROY event from DialogBox

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

While elaborating an answer for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30720956/3258851) (by myself), I've come up with the idea of using a MessageBox to report the result of my dialog box. It is a WinAPI modal dialog box created with the `DialogBox()` function.

However, I noticed that handling `WM_DESTROY` in the dialog's procedure function will prevent the message box from appearing. I would like to understand the mechanics behind that.

Here's the full code, and the referred message box is at the end, right before `return 0`:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "resource.h"

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    // uncomment these and the MessageBox won't show up
    //case WM_DESTROY:
        //PostQuitMessage(0);
        //break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
            if (MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Close the window?", L"Confirm", MB_OKCANCEL) == IDOK)
                EndDialog(hwnd, (INT_PTR)wParam);
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            MessageBoxW(hwnd, L"Goodbye.", L"Close", MB_OK);
            EndDialog(hwnd, (INT_PTR)TRUE);
            break;
        }
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    INT_PTR ret = DialogBoxW(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, DlgProc);

    wchar_t retTxt[10];
    if (ret == IDOK)
        wcscpy(retTxt, L"Alright!");
    else
        wcscpy(retTxt, L"Error");

    MessageBoxW(NULL, retTxt, L"Result", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `DialogBox` rather than `DialogBoxParam`, the dialog runs its own message loop that handles `WM_DESTROY` internally. When you post the `WM_QUIT` message from your dialog procedure you are generating an additional message* that the dialog box won't use, so it remains in your thread's message queue once the `DialogBox` function returns.

You then call `MessageBox`, which runs its own message loop. This immediately pulls the `WM_QUIT` out of the queue, exits the loop and returns before the dialog is even displayed.

(* actually it's not a "real" message - an internal flag is set that indicates quit has been posted - but the effect is the same on the subsequent message loop)

Comment: Then I should not call `PostQuitMessage()` from within my function? If you have a link explaining which events are handled internally for dialogs, please share. Thanks!

Comment: Probably worth noting `WM_QUIT` via `PostQuitMessage()` is not a *real* "message" sitting the message queue. Like `WM_TIMER`, `WM_PAINT`, and others, it is a status bit (more or less) and a low priority one at that. When someone asks for a message *and* the queue is otherwise-"empty" a `WM_QUIT` will be manufactured and delivered to the requestor.

Comment: @WhozCraig If you think it will help the OP's clarity :)

Comment: It should, as it helps (at least in little) in seeing how that message stays 'stuck' in the thread message queue. Raymond Chen has a good, though brief, somewhat related article about it at [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/04/489028.aspx).