# Is it possible to specify a COM dialog to use from a resource file?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is it possible to use windows resources to define a dialog that will call a 
standard FileOpenDialog?
The idea is to replace code such as the one pasted below [(source)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485843(v=vs.85).aspx) with resource file entries (maybe [DIALOG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381003(v=vs.85).aspx) or [DIALOGEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381002(v=vs.85).aspx)?)

Is this possible?

```
/* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485843(v=vs.85).aspx  */
#include <windows.h>
#include <shobjidl.h> 

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | 
        COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen;

        // Create the FileOpenDialog object.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
                IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Show the Open dialog box.
            hr = pFileOpen->Show(NULL);

            // Get the file name from the dialog box.
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                IShellItem *pItem;
                hr = pFileOpen->GetResult(&pItem);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    PWSTR pszFilePath;
                    hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);

                    // Display the file name to the user.
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        MessageBox(NULL, pszFilePath, L"File Path", MB_OK);
                        CoTaskMemFree(pszFilePath);
                    }
                    pItem->Release();
                }
            }
            pFileOpen->Release();
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Background to the question**

I am following the MSDN tutorials from [MSDEV center](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381399(v=vs.85).aspx)
and also at examples elsewhere that show windows resource files compiled with "rc", the resource compiler.

I recently saw an example where a whole "About" dialog is specified in a resource file and referenced in the windows program using "DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTDIALOG), hWnd, &AboutDialogProc)" [(link)](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/win32-apps-with-mingw/)

```
IDD_ABOUTDIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 147, 67
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION |     WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
  ICON             IDI_APPICON,IDC_STATIC,7,7,20,20
  LTEXT            "Win32 Test application.",IDC_STATIC,34,7,86,8
  LTEXT            "©2013 Transmission Zero",IDC_STATIC,34,17,86,8
  DEFPUSHBUTTON    "OK",IDOK,90,46,50,14,WS_GROUP
END
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Dialog resources are not a code generation tool. They describe how to create windows and position them, that's all.

Comment: The dialog editor is like the poor man's UI designer.  Point and click design is pretty convenient but you still have to bring the code to use it.  A minimal program [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10233086/17034).

Comment: The standard dialogs are there for a reason. Please don't try to reinvent the wheel by implementing your own file dialog, which will lack in functionality and will look "oldschool" a few years from now, when new functionality and/or design is added to the standard dialogs. Just write little wrapper functions around `IFileOpenDialog` / `IFileSaveDialog` so you don't have to repeat yourself everytime you need to call a file dialog.

Comment: Is your question about making a dialog or making a custom FileOpenDialog?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The only part of your code that creates a dialog is the `CoCreateInstance` call. Everything else is just code to *interact* with the dialog. Even if it were possible to create an `IFileOpenDialog` from a resource, it would be *more* work to do so. This is probably all due to your observation being wrong, that the resource script you posted were indeed the entire dialog. It isn't. The `DialogBox` function expects at least a dialog procedure. That's where all the interaction code is. You need to get Petzold's book on Windows API programming.

Answer (score 0):

No and honestly as worded your question doesn't make much sense.

Resources are simply data, they provide no implementation of their own. (A dialog is instantiated from a template by the DialogBox* function family reading the template and creating each of the indicated controls in turn, not by the compiled resource somehow encapsulating already instantiated controls).

If you want the file open dialog to appear when your own dialog is created you can handle the WM_INITDIALOG message with code like your above (the parts between CoInitialize / CoUninitialize), more normally would be to have a button or menu item for which you receive a WM_COMMAND message when the item is triggered.